# Raspbian on RPi - Python script runs in IDLE shell but not cmd

Tags: python, linux, shell, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I wrote this script that turns on and off the GPIO pins, at different intervals, simultaneously. It works in IDLE shell but not when accessed from the cmd with: sudo python onoff.py

A similar script without the threading works fine from the cmd. (Just turns one GPIO on and off)

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
from time import sleep  
import thread

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  

GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)  
GPIO.setup(13, GPIO.OUT)  
GPIO.setup(15, GPIO.OUT)  

def fast():  
    while True:  
        GPIO.output(11, True)  
        sleep(.02)  
        GPIO.output(11, False)  
        sleep(.02)  

def med():
    while True:
        GPIO.output(13, True)
        sleep(.2)
        GPIO.output(13, False)
        sleep(.2)

def slow():
    while True:
        GPIO.output(15, True)
        sleep(2)
        GPIO.output(15, False)
        sleep(2)

thread.start_new_thread(fast,())
thread.start_new_thread(med,())
thread.start_new_thread(slow,())
```

Comment: why you need threading here????

Comment: So that they are all turning on off at different intervals. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out thanks to [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475268/thread-start-new-thread-not-working/27475304#27475304)

"It's because there is no main program/loop. Your code starts those threads, but then it will come to the end of the code and exit the process running python, killing the threads. So maybe add a raw_input("Press enter to exit") at the bottom."